# Sum chosen columns until meeting a condition on Excel

Tags: excel, multiple-columns

I want to be able to sum columns until a Condition is met, but also be able to peek them based on their headers.

**My partial pivot:**
[image]

|  | WC 11 | WC 12 | WC 13 | WC 21 | WC 22 | WC 23 | WC 31 | WC 32 | WC 33 | WC 41 | WC 42 | WC 43 | WC 44 | WC 51 | WC 61 | WC 62 | WC 63 | WC 64 | WC 71 | WC 72 | WC 73 | WC 74 | WC 76 | WC 77 | WC 81 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 37 Order-1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 4.9 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 37 Order-2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0.7 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 32 Order-1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 32 Order-10 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 10.75 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 32 Order-11 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1.5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 32 Order-12 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2.2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 32 Order-13 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2.2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 32 Order-14 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1.9 |
| 32 Order-15 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0.7 |
| 32 Order-16 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 32 Order-17 | 7.1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 32 Order-18 | 0.3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

**Expected output (BLUE):**

[image]

I tried to merge `SUM`, `MATCH`, and `INDEX`, but left with no solution.
English is not my native language! I would be happy if you would edit the question so it could be more readable. Thanks!

Comment: This would be much easier to help if the data was text that we can copy paste instead of a picture we have to manually reproduce.

Comment: I added a table to copy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUM and two index matches:

```
=SUM(INDEX($B$2:$Z$2,,MATCH(B17,$B$1:$Z$1,0)):INDEX($B$2:$Z$13,MATCH(A17,$A$2:$A$13,0),MATCH(B17,$B$1:$Z$1,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Our tables do not match (look at first row of your upper table compared to my pic, and the final two rows of bottom table compared to my outcome pic).

Comment: @ron, that is just a matter of changing the references.

Comment: AMAZING! Thats it! thank you so much :)